# How is the function $|z|^2$ nowhere analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

Putting $z=x+iy,f(z)=|z|^2=(x^2-y^2)+2ixy$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=2x $$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}= -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-2y $$ so it satisfies Cauchy Riemann equation. But it is nowhere analytic. How? 
Yes I did an error in taking $|z|^2$.
So now I got how it works. Thanks lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've made an error in representing $|z|^2$ -- it's $x^2 + y^2$, not $(x^2 - y^2) + 2xy i$ (which instead represents $z^2$).

Comment: 's answer thanks for ur suggestion

Comment: I am unable to write the partial differential operators. That one I wrote wrongly in questions. Will u help?

Comment: I've made the changes, but for future reference, the command you use for partials is \partial, which produces $\partial$.

Answer (score 1):

The Cauchy-Riemann conditions(sufficient) are indeed satisfied everywhere, and all the partials are elementary funnctions, and as such are differentiable on the whole plane. The function is indeed holomorphic on every region in $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: The function $g(z) = z^2$. Not the function $f(z) = \lvert z\rvert^2$.

Comment: Sorry, it was well after 11pm when I wrote the answer.